# Check repetition of fractions of external file

Tags: java, class, fractions

I'm creating a program that has a requirement of three classes. The program reads an external text file filled with fractions, and is to return how many times each fraction is repeated. 4/2 has to be reduced to 2/1 and is +1 for the 2/1 count. I believe I am almost done, but I cannot figure out what I need to put into my `compareAndIncrement()` method in my `FractionCounter` class. It is suppose to be used to see if the newFraction passed into the function is the same as the Fraction being stored, and if so increments the counter by one and returns true (otherwise, returns false). Below are the codes for my classes.

**FractionCounter**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class FractionCounter {

    private Fraction theFraction;
    private int counter = 0;

    public FractionCounter(Fraction theFraction ){

    }

    public boolean compareAndIncrement(Fraction newFraction){

        return false;
    }

    public String toString(){

        return "";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        ObjectList num = new ObjectList();
        ObjectList den = new ObjectList();

        Scanner fractionFile = null;

        try{
            fractionFile = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("fractions.txt"));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println("File not found."); 
            System.exit(0); 
        }

        while (fractionFile.hasNextLine()){
            String[] part = (fractionFile.nextLine().split("/"));
            num.add(Integer.parseInt(part[0]));
            den.add(Integer.parseInt(part[1]));

        }   
    }
}
```

**Fraction**

```
public class Fraction {

    private int numerator;
    private int denominator;

    public Fraction() {
    }

    public Fraction(int num, int den) {
        setNumerator(num);
        setDenominator(den);
    }

    public void setNumerator(int num) { //sets numerator
        numerator = num;
    }

    public int getNumerator() { //gets numerator
        return numerator;
    }

    public void setDenominator(int den) { //sets denominator
        if(den == 0) {
            System.out.println("Error: Denominator = 0");
            System.exit(0);
        } else {
            denominator = den;
        }
    }
    public int getDenominator() { //gets denominator
        return denominator;
    }
    public boolean equals(Fraction that) { 

        return ((double)this.numerator/this.denominator) == ((double)that.numerator/that.denominator);

    }
}
```

**ObjectList**

```
public class ObjectList {
    private int[] fraction = new int[100];
    private int numElements = 0;

    public void add(int n){
        fraction[numElements] = n;
        numElements++;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String retVal = "";
        for (int i = 0;  i < numElements; i++){
            retVal += fraction[i] + ",";
        }
        return retVal;
    }

    public int indexOf(int[] input, int target) { 
        //returns the index of the inputed value
        if(contains(input,target) == true){
            for(int i = 0;i <= target;i++) {
                if(input[i] == target) {
                    return i;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public boolean contains(int[] input, int target) { 
        //is the target in the inputed array?
        for(int i=0;i<input.length; i++) {
            if(input[i] == target) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }



}
```

Any hints or tips for what I need to do to my method would be much appreciated. I can't figure out a way to do it without using `numElements` and `fraction` variables from my `ObjectList` class. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would make a Map to make the counter :

```
private static final Map<Fraction, Integer> counter = new HashMap<Fraction, Integer>();
```

and for each Fraction element read for the file I would do :

```
if(counter.containsKey(fraction)){
    Integer count = counter.get(fraction);
    count++;
    counter.put(fraction, count);
} else {
    counter.put(fraction, 1);
}
```

Moreover, I would make a static parse fonction in the Fraction class which return a Fraction instance from the line you just read. And a toString function to print it easely.